# GWT Base64 to image client side

Tags: java, gwt

How to convert base64 encoding of an image to image on client side in GWT?

I have already tried `Image image = new Image(base64String)` but it didn't work for me. Any leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing should work on the client side.

Make sure you're passing the data correctly on the server side, for example:

```
public String getImage(){
      String imgData = "data:image/png;base64," +  Base64Utils.toBase64(imageByteArray); 
      return imgData ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Image img = new Image("clear.cache.gif");
img.setPixelSize(100, 100);
img.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url(data:image/png;base64," + base64String + ")");
```

Just set image size and content type (png/jpeg) with proper values.

`clear.cache.gif` is standard GWT 1x1 transparent gif image.

And remember that older IE browsers has limitation on style value length, so you can have problems with large images.